# find the same matrixes using awk or sed

Tags: matrix, sed, awk

I have 3x3 matrix groups. How can I delete equal matrixes  using awk or sed?
Thanks

Example data

```
1###########################

303

301

100

2###########################

120

001

212

3###########################

230

030

210

4###########################

211

211

100

5###########################

111

313

300

6###########################

230

330

232
```

Comment: does it matter what the number before the hashes is?  because some of those are going to go.  and does it really have to be awk/sed, or can it be any command line tools?  oh, and your example contains no duplicates, right?

Comment: I have almost  10-page document including these matrixes. Some of them are the same. In the example there are no same matrixes

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED #3** (similarity removed)

Try something like this:

```
awk -v OFS="\n" '
function swap(q) {w=a[q];a[q]=a[q+1];a[q+1]=w}
function akin(t,x,y) {gsub(x,"#",t);gsub(y,x,t);gsub("#",y,t);return t}
function look() {
  k=a[1]"."a[2]"."a[3]
  if(k in m) return 1
  #for(j=0;j<6;++j) { # Make permutations
      #k=a[1]"."a[2]"."a[3]
      m[k]
      m[akin(k,1,2)]
      m[akin(k,1,3)]
      m[akin(k,2,3)]
      #swap(j%2+1)
  #}
  return 0
}
/^[[:space:]]*$/{next} # Skip empty lines
{a[i++]=$0} # Store data
i==4 { # Process data
  i=0
  if (look()) next;
  print a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]
}
' data
```

It defines two functions. `swap` swaps two elements in array `a` and `look` check is `a` is in the `m` check hash. If not it adds `a` all permutations to `m` (`a[0]` is not considered).

Then reads four lines and creates a key from the matrix rows. If the key already exists then skip. Otherwise print data. If the empty lines have importance then add `"\n"` to end of each `print` line.

Output:

```
1###########################
303
301
100
2###########################
120
001
212
3###########################
230
030
210
4###########################
211
211
100
5###########################
111
313
300
6###########################
230
330
232
```

Comment: In the matrixes, coulumns can be replaced with each other and matrix is still the same. How can you  extend code considering this? Thanks

Comment: Two matrices are not equal if two columns are changed. E.g. The determinant can be *-1. But I'll think about it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is very useful. You are right. if we exchange columns, they can be considered as equal in my case only.
 I need such a code now, two matrix are equal  if sum of the rows are equal. Thanks

Comment: @GaripFakir: Huh. I'm a little bit confused what is your goal! If the sum of each individual rows and columns are identical to the same values of an other marix it is considered as equal? What about transposition? Please provide examples!

Comment: In each data group, there  three independent column

Comment: In each data group, there  are three independent column that their rows represent x y z coordinates. Two matrix that have the same columns, will put  points to  the same places. thanks

Comment: @GaripFakir: Still not clear! Is the first `[x1 x2 x3]` or `[x1 y1 z1]`?

Comment: First column is x1 y1 z1. Thanks

Comment: @GaripFakir: I think I solved the issue.

Comment: Lastly I would like to find similar matrices also:

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are wanderful. A last request.  I would like to find similar matrices also. If you notice in my matrices there are only 0, 1, 2 and 3 as number. Similarity rule can be defined as follows. except zeros, if two numbers are exhanged with each other (except zeros)  they are similar. For example [1,2,0;
0,0,3;2,1,2].If I exchange 2 and 3 (2->3 and 3->2) I can obtain a similar matrix as follows [1,3,0;
0,0,2;3,1,3]. there are other combinations also (1->3 and 3->1) 3,2,0;0,0,1;2,3,2], (1->2 and 2->1) [2,1,0;0,0,3;1,2,1]. In this similarity, zeros cannot be used in exchange.

Comment: @GaripFakir: I modified the code accordingly.

Comment: I idid not mean this. when I wrote 1<->3, I mean that put number 1 instead of number 3 and put number 3 instead of number 1. Not the column but number it self. Could you please  look at my sismilar matrix again. For example [1,2,0; 0,0,3;2,1,2].If I exchange 2 and 3 (2->3 and 3->2) I can obtain a similar matrix as follows [1,3,0; 0,0,2;3,1,3]. there are other combinations also (1->3 and 3->1) 3,2,0;0,0,1;2,3,2], (1->2 and 2->1) [2,1,0;0,0,3;1,2,1]. I am exhanging numbers not columns in this speacial case. Thanks

Comment: @GaripFakir: I try to describe what I understood: There are two level of similarity: #1 rows are in different order; #2 Numbers (>0) can be changed (1<->2, 1<->3, 2<->3). The above code does both of them. If You need one of them, You can just remove that part.

Comment: In this code fist similarity rule is dominant and the code ignores second similarity rule. Could you please put my example  matrices in your code and see they are ignored

Comment: In this code fist similarity rule is dominant and the code ignores second similarity rule. Could you please put my example  matrices in your code and see they are ignored, this [1,2,0; 0,0,3;2,1,2].  [1,3,0; 0,0,2;3,1,3].  [3,2,0;0,0,1;2,3,2], [2,1,0;0,0,3;1,2,1]. Could you please remove and test first part. THANKS

Comment: I mean could you please remove first column exchange part and  give the code for number exchange. I could not remove the first part. I gave my example matrices also. THANKS

Comment: The code is too complex for me now. Really I could not remove first part.  ;(

Comment: @GaripFakir: None of the similarities are dominant. I do not really understand what is your point, but I removed the row-swap part. Now only the number-changing part remained.

Comment: Now we exchange all numbers with each other,  columns are exchanged  and zeros keep their places. Therefore extended version of this similarity can be like this. While columns are exchanged,  matrices that have same zero can be similar.  Since numbers can be exchanged,  only place of the zeros are important.  Thanks.

Comment: @GaripFakir: Actually columns are not exchanged. Just the numbers are. Is it ok now?

Comment: It is good but I also would like to extend this similarity. What happens if all numbers are replaced by each other? that means zeros will keep their places, so this is another kind of similarity. Could you please update the code. THANKS

Comment: @GaripFakir: Please try to collect your ideas and write the problem in an other question. I do not really understand your needs which are always changing. Sorry, but it is very difficult for me to help you.

Comment: Thank you  you helped me in perfect way. You improved the code for the special case.